# AOSP Changes unnoticed for months - is an automatic step missing

Tags: android-source, gerrit

Several *small* contributions to the Android Source code are lying around unnoticed for months, e.g [this one](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/156625/). Is there any automatic step which was not triggered? I noticed the Deckard Autoverifier on several other changes but not on this one?

How can I trigger all automatic steps needed before a human might look at the patch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to add some of the contributors of the same package as reviewers. 
In your case, look thru https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/q/project:platform/frameworks/base and add some of the active developers there.

Also find out who made the code and add them as reviewers.

If that doensent bear fruit within a few months or so you can try to write a mail to the android-contrib mailing list. 
Promoting individual patches is off-topic so your mail wont get thru, but the human which reject such is usually helpfull and will try to find someone that can look at your patch.

Yes, its not the way open source is usually working. Expect that it might take half a year for the patch to get thru, unless it catches the interest of some of the current developers.